# Concrete example of an entire function wanted

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-dynamics

Let $X$ be the space of entire functions on $\mathbb{C}$ endowed with the topology of uniform convergence on compact sets. Let $a$ be a nonzero complex number. Let $T: X\to X$ be defined by $T(f)(z)=f(z+a)$. By a result of Birkhoff (see Dynamics of Linear Operators, by F. Bayart and E. Matheron, p. 3), there exists an $f\in X$ such that $O(f,T)=\{T^nf: n=0,1,2,\cdots\}$ is dense in $X$.

Does anyone know a concrete example of such $f$?

Answer (score 2):

Except the Riemann Zeta function and similar functions (which are not entire functions), no concrete example is known so far.

For a survey of known results, I suggest you take a look at the recent papers by Paul Gauthier, e.g. [this one](http://www.heldermann-verlag.de/cmf/cmf10/cmf10032.pdf). After Theorem 13, there is a remark saying that no concrete example of universal entire functions is known.

Answer (score 0):

Such  functions are called universal. The Riemann Zeta function was the first function to be known to have universal properties.
See this [link](http://mathsexperiences.wordpress.com/2011/06/27/universality-of-the-riemann-zeta-function/) and these [slides](http://cumc.math.ca/2011/Slides/ThibaultLouisPhilippe.pdf).
The right formulation of Voronin theorem is given in the latter one. There is a typo in the former one: $f(z)$ should be instead of $\zeta(z)$.

Comment: The Riemann Zeta function is not entire. As far as I know, there is no known concrete example of universal entire function.